# How to map existing tables into a inheritance hierarchy in NHibernate?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

The problem is trying to map inheritance given an existing table structure.  The table is also used by legacy apps using raw sql, ie, the table can't delete any existing schema details, but can add more to it.

The existing table is already mapped, and essentially has a bunch of fields with the following problem....

so existing class

```
class A
{
    // Id etc
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

with a table structure like

```
 table A (
        Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
       Client_id INT null,
       primary key (Id)
    )
```

Now I want to introduce a base class

```
class Base
{
   // Id etc
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}
```

which will end up with a table like...

```
   table Base (
       Id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
       Client_id INT null,  
       primary key (Id)
    )
```

and change A to

```
class A : Base
{
   // clients moved to the base...
}
```

which will do something like this to the table :-

```
table A(
           Base_id INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
           Id INT not null,     // I will need to keep the existing Id field...
           Client_id INT null,  // this Client now conflicts with the Base client
           primary key (Base_id)
        )
```

I'm using table per class inheritance.

the problem is....

'Client' will be on the table of "Base" and also it's on the existing table of "A".  I want to be able to keep using the 'Client' on "A", as a kind of override.

How do I do this? can I do this?

or is it possible that on table "Base" it doesn't have 'Client' at all and then on all the subclass tables they define "Client"?   (which would make querying interesting)

Comment: This whole 'A' 'Base' 'Client' really makes your question difficult to understand for me. Can you supply a cut down version of your table structure and classes. Will make it easier to determine what the mapping requirements are.

Comment: trying to make it clearer :-)   the basic problem is the field Client appears in both tables, and normally when subclassing you'd only have it on the base.   At least as far as my understanding goes.

Comment: Hmm, Client doesn't really become inherited then, if you have client on the base, what about it differs on the sub-table. If you stored the clientid 4 on the base, and 'override' it with client 7 in the subbed class, how does that differ from having the base updated to 7? I don't think base is really being used as a 'base' it's more like it's own class.

Comment: It defines the interface.   Anything of "Base" will have a client.   Ideally you can query for all the "Base" things belonging to a Client, which would return all the various subclasses inherting from base with that particular client.   All of that works perfectly in normal circumstances.   But here, I have the problem I can't change the legacy table of A and move the field client to the table for 'Base'

Comment: If the base class defines Client, then the subbed classes automatically have Client. If A happens to also define Client, then that client is technically different to Base Client. You would have Client and ClientA (two properties). You can't override the mapping of base in your subbed map. If each subbed class defines it's own Client, then those are technically different on each subbed class, I don't think querying would be possible even if defined on an interface since I don't think you can query against the interface.

Comment: Tricky scenario. I think you should have A.Client2 and use that over Client, once all your queries have been updated so anything using A is up to date. Then do a data-migration of A.Client2 to Base.Client, and then modify the queries to call A.Client. If that makes sense.

Comment: yes, I know.  But to be clear..... its the TABLE of A that has client... the class itself will inherit client off of the Base.  But I want it to get the value of Client from Table A rather than from the Base when fetching an object of class 'A'.   And yes, if it has to query for Client, this would be funky join.

Comment: just hunting around, table per concrete class may do what I want.... just investigating.

Answer (score 0):

if its only for querying NH should support Querying by interface

```
class A : IHasClient
{
    // Id etc
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

class SomeOther : IHasClient
{
    // Id etc
    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}


var classesWithClients = session.QueryOver<IHasClient>().List();
```

Comment: and collections,  I'll also want to put things in a IList<IHasClient> type thing